# Besides intended usage, what is the difference between a host key and a user key?

Tags: openssh

The ssh-keygen program has -h flag for creating a host key. What is the actual difference between keys created with and without -h? Is there any reason I could/should not use a host key as a user key or vice versa?

Comment: Hmm, keys are used for authentication for server and client. ssh-keygen utility distributes keys across the file system according to the intended use. You can hack into this process and flip-flop them or you can just use an appropriate flag such as -h for the server key. ssh-keygen -h also replaces the existing server key, which means the server would need to re-authenticate to its clients.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered if replacing the existing host key might be a part of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** you can use the same key to either create a host or a user certificate; you can put limitations to user certificates but not to host certificates (for now, anyways).

**In detail:**

> The ssh-keygen program has -h flag for creating a host key

No, the `-h` flag is only used when you sign the key. From the [ssh-keygen man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html)<sup>1</sup>:

```
-h      When signing a key, create a host certificate instead of a user certificate. Please see the CERTIFICATES section for details
```

> What is the actual difference between keys created with and without -h?

The actual functionality is *keys signed with and without -h*. The answer lies in the `CERTIFICATES` section of the manual page:

```
ssh-keygen supports signing of keys to produce certificates that may be used for user or host authentication

[...]

ssh-keygen supports two types of certificates: user and host.  User certificates authenticate users to servers, whereas host certificates authenticate server hosts to users. [...]
```

The difference is this:

```
[...]

Additional limitations on the validity and use of user certificates may be specified through certificate options. A certificate option may disable features of the SSH session, may be valid only when presented from particular source addresses or may force the use of a specific command.

[...]

At present, no standard options are valid for host keys.
```

---

<sup>1</sup> for Ubuntu Impish, but it's similar to other distros